# Discord.js how add role with id and have a server cooldown 2 hour

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

> Discordjs version 11.4.2
>
> how add role and server cooldown
>
> check server id first if server id = 426626817596850177
>
> then check cooldown
>
> if have a cooldown sent message to channel have a cooldown in server
>
> if don't have a cooldown then addroleid role id = 710057293315571774

```
if(message.content === 'add role'){
  message.member.addrole???
}
```

Comment: Please keep your questions separate, make another question about the cooldown when you can.

Comment: @Syntle It is not the role of moderators to change questions.  If you feel it is too broad, then vote to close as such.

Comment: Alright, noted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole) to do add a role to a `GuildMember`

```js
if(message.content === 'add role'){
  message.member.addRole(ROLE_ID)
}
```